# multiprocessing with nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Is there a way to pass a nested dictionary to multiprocessing?

```
d = {'a': {'x': 1, 'y':100},
     'b': {'x': 2, 'y':200}}
```

I was hoping to start two parallel jobs, one for `{'a': {'x':1, 'y':100}}` and another for `{'b': {'x': 2, 'y':200}}`, and use the following function to create a new dictionary

```
def f(d):
    key = dd.keys()
    new_d[key]['x'] = d[key]['x']*2
    new_d[key]['y'] = d[key]['y']*2
```

This was my unsuccessful attempt

```
import multiprocessing

def f(key, d, container):
    container[key]['x'] = d[key]['x']*2
    container[key]['y'] = d[key]['y']*2
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    container = manager.dict()
    d = manager.dict()
    
    d['a'] = {'x': 1, 'y':100}
    d['b'] = {'x': 2, 'y':200}
        
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('a',d, container))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('b',d, container))
    
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

I get a `KeyError: 'b'` and also, I would like to avoid having to specify the number of processes manually, like `p1` and `p2` and so on. Is there maybe another way?

Comment: try `container[key] = {}` before the 2 other line, without you won't be able to assign the 2nd level

Comment: @azro, your solution won't give me any errors, but `print(container)` results in `{'a': {}, 'b': {}}`

Comment: @azro, yes, I did, I added `container[key] = {}` just before the other two lines in `f`. Does it work with you?

Comment: Regardless of the right answer to your immediate question.  Creating a shared dictionary and having multiple threads modifying it is almost certainly a bad idea.  One thread actually owns the object, and the others manipulate it by proxy.

Answer (score 2):

@nonDucor is right: You have to create the nested dictionaries using the `Manager` object.

The following is an abbreviated solution using more Pythonic dictionary creation, as well as using the `ProcessPoolExecutor` interface for concurrency:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Executor
import multiprocessing

def f(key, d, container):
    container[key]['x'] = d[key]['x'] * 2
    container[key]['y'] = d[key]['y'] * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    d = manager.dict({
        'a': manager.dict({'x': 1, 'y': 100}),
        'b': manager.dict({'x': 2, 'y': 200}),
    })
    container = manager.dict({x: manager.dict() for x in d.keys()})
    with Executor() as exe:
        exe.submit(f, 'a', d, container)
        exe.submit(f, 'b', d, container)
        
    for the_dict in (d, container):
        print([the_dict[x].items() for x in the_dict.keys()])
```

For comparison, below we use **multithreading** instead of **multiprocessing**. Since memory is shared by both threads, there's no need for protected dictionaries--plain old dicts work just fine. But to make the target dictionary more dynamic and independent of the source `dict` upon creation, we use the `defaultdict` of `defaultdict`s data structure:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Executor

def f(key, d, container):
    container[key]['x'] = d[key]['x'] * 2
    container[key]['y'] = d[key]['y'] * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d ={
        'a': {'x': 1, 'y': 100},
        'b': {'x': 2, 'y': 200},
    }
    container = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    with Executor() as exe:
        exe.submit(f, 'a', d, container)
        exe.submit(f, 'b', d, container)
        
    for the_dict in (d, container):
        print([the_dict[x].items() for x in the_dict.keys()])
```

Answer (score 1):

The nested dicts also have to be managed. I added this step in your code and also made everything dependent on the members of `d`, so you don't have to deal with `p1`, `p2`, etc:

```py
import multiprocessing

def f(key, d, container):
    container[key]['x'] = d[key]['x']*2
    container[key]['y'] = d[key]['y']*2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    container = manager.dict()
    d = manager.dict()

    d['a'] = {'x': 1, 'y':100}
    d['b'] = {'x': 2, 'y':200}

    # This line initialises the nested dicts
    for key in d:
        container[key] = manager.dict()

    # Here we create a list with the processes we started
    processes = []
    for key in d:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(key ,d, container))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    # And finally wait for all of them to finish
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    # Show the results
    print(container['a'])
    print(container['b'])
```

The `multiprocessing.Pool` class may be a better solution to your problem though (check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool))